# multiple simplexml_load_file in one variable

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to load multiple XML files into a variable called $xml.

I have an array ($all_urls) that contains the path to each XML file.
To acheive this goal I used a method I found here on StackOverflow.

```
    foreach ($all_urls as $url) 
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
}
```

However, using this simple foreach - $xml only contains the last loaded file. For example, if '$all_urls' contains 'file.xml' and 'file2.xml' , only rows from 'file2.xml' are availible in $xml.

Is what I want to do possible? I have seen some code that uses DOM, but I need to stick to SimpleXML. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
As per requested, an (shortened) example of one of the XML documents.

http://pastebin.com/Yj54w1HS

Comment: Is each file a complete XML document, or is it XML snippets?

Comment: pls show those different XMLs as examples. Edit your question and add these.

Comment: They are complete XML documents. I will add an example in my question as per requested.

Comment: _“$xml only contains the last loaded file”_ – well naturally so, because you are overwriting the variable in each loop. Use an array instead – put each simpleXML object into the array as a new element, then you can loop over that array again later to do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: "I have seen some code that uses DOM, but I need to stick to SimpleXML" Note that you can mix DOM and SimpleXML in PHP with no penalty, as they are both wrappers around the same structure in memory. See [`simplexml_import_dom()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php) and [`dom_import_simplexml()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php), so you should be able to write a self-contained function to merge the documents using DOM methods, then manipulate the result using SimpleXML.

Comment: **shortened example??** please provide the minimum amount of code necessary, the pasted XML is way too much, please simplify to demonstrate its structure. Do all of your XMLs share the same structure, and are id's etc unique?